# move <someone> on

Tags: meaning, phrasal-verbs

Source: [Alliances crumble along the Crimean border](http://www.aljazeera.com/indepth/features/2015/12/alliances-crumble-crimean-border-151219110155013.html)

Example:

> "Of course the Tatars are not leaving. We will stay and more people will come to help us. The Ukrainian forces from Kherson have already come several times to try to **move us on** with guns and bullets, but it came to nothing," he said.

What exactly does that mean? To make someone leave a place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a super common construction, but the meaning becomes clear in the context.

The speaker says,

> . . . the Tatars are not leaving. We will stay . . . [they have tried] to **move us on** . . . but it came to nothing.

So in other words, since we don't know what "move us on" means...

> We aren't leaving. We will stay. They tried to ______, but it didn't work.

It makes sense that the meaning is "get us to move" in this context.

Again, I don't think that this is a common construction. According to [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=move%20us%20on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmove%20us%20on%3B%2Cc0), it's pretty rare (0.000000500%).

Answer (score 1):

It does mean to get someone to leave. Check out the definition in the British Dictionary section [here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/move--on?s=t). That's not everything, though. The cute part is that to get someone to move on is to make them stop gawking or standing around idly and get on with whatever business they're supposed to be occupied with.

I.e. "Get the hell out of here *and* mind your own damn business."

Those Tatars are intriguing people. I mean, do they call in sick every day, or is this a paid vacation, or what? How do they pay rent?

Ah, yes, I almost forgot. The expression is awkward. It should be

> "They've tried to get us to move on."